# Fastest way to render image data from buffer

Tags: rendering, sdl, sdl2

Currently I am doing my rendering by using a 3D array window_width x window_height x rgb as a buffer, then looping through the buffer and plotting pixels on screen using SDL2 (SDL_RenderDrawPoint). I know this is horrible and stupidly slow but I am not well experienced in graphics techniques. What is the better way to do this?

Comment: Why not use a 1D array of `SDL_Texture`s that you render using `SDL_RenderCopy`? Why do you need a buffer of these anyway?

Comment: I'm building a ray tracer and my render algorithm puts each calculated pixel into the array, which I then render to screen. Can I put the pixel data into a texture, then copy it using RenderCopy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SDL_LockTexture](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LockTexture) and [SDL_UnlockTexture](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_UnlockTexture) for **write only** access to a texture created with the `SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING` flag. Lock, write, unlock, then use `SDL_RenderCopy` to blit to the screen.

Create the buffer with [SDL_CreateTexture](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateTexture) (modify to you liking):

```
SDL_Texture* buffer = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer,
                           SDL_PIXELFORMAT_BGRA8888,
                           SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, 
                           800,
                           600);
```

Lock with [SDL_LockTexture](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LockTexture):

```
SDL_LockTexture(buffer,
                NULL,      // NULL means the *whole texture* here.
                &pixels,
                &pitch);
```

Where `pixels` is a `int *` and [pitch](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/96564/66352) is the width of a row of pixels in bytes.

Write your pixel data to `pixels`. You won't have any of the convenient SDL functions to do this. Just plonk the data in, one pixel after the other until you have done them all. Make sure you write with the correct PIXELFORMAT, otherwise the colours will come out wonky. (In `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_BGRA8888`, the first byte is blue, second is green, third is red and fourth is alpha. Leave alpha at 255 unless you want transparency)

Clean up with [SDL_UnlockTexture](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_UnlockTexture):

```
SDL_UnlockTexture(buffer);
```

Then you can [RenderCopy](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopy) this texture as normal:

```
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, buffer, NULL, NULL);
```

This assumes the buffer is the same size as your window.

Note you will have to modify this for your own use case.

Comment: Do you know around what point it becomes beneficial to write to pixels pixel by pixel instead of `SDL_RenderCopy`? It seems like a 32x32 px section is relatively slow to use `SDL_RenderCopy` on, what is the limit where it no longer makes sense to write data pixel by pixel?